# Keep Getting this error in my python Code : Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to start my backend with `Uvicorn main:app --reload`  but It refuses to start and keeps giving me an error and im not sure what to do anymore as I keep fixing one problem and getting another when it comes to this project.I would greatly appreciate some help with this problem.

Here is my main.py code

```
from . import models
from fastapi import FastAPI

from .database import engine
from .routers import books, users,authentication

app=FastAPI()
models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

app.include_router(books.router)
app.include_router(users.router)
app.include_router(authentication.router)
```

Here is the error that I keep facing

````
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [4840] using StatReload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\backends\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from jose.backends.cryptography_backend import CryptographyRSAKey as RSAKey  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\backends\cryptography_backend.py", line 4, in <module>
    from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature, InvalidTag
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uvicorn.config import Config
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "C:\Users\darkg\OneDrive\Desktop\loginpage\FastAP_Backend\books\.\token.py", line 4, in <module>
    from jose import JWTError, jwt
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\jwt.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jose import jws
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\jws.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jose import jwk
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\jwk.py", line 1, in <module>
    from jose.backends.base import Key
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\backends\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jose.backends.rsa_backend import RSAKey  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\backends\rsa_backend.py", line 9, in <module>
    from jose.backends._asn1 import (
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\jose\backends\_asn1.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder, encoder
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\der\decoder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pyasn1.codec.cer import decoder
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\cer\decoder.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pyasn1 import debug
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\debug.py", line 63, in <module>
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'Handler' (most likely due to a circular import) ```
````

I installed cryptography and now im getting this instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uvicorn.config import Config
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "C:\Users\darkg\OneDrive\Desktop\loginpage\FastAP_BackEnd\books\.\token.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import schemas
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've tried running it with ``` python -m Uvicorn main:app --reload

```
but im still getting the same error as before.
```

Comment: You are missing the `cryptography` module : https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/, try to run  `pip install cryptography`

Comment: Hello Thanks for the help, but im still getting the error sadly , but I think it did get smaller.

Comment: You are running a module as main module that uses relative imports. Run it with `python -m ...` instead.

Comment: I tried that and it gives the same error